# Get multiple items given an arbitrary query -> Python FastAPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, fastapi-crudrouter

Get multiple items given an arbitrary query. I am trying to achieve this using Python Fastapi, this is what I did in routes,

```
def get_props_query(

    *,
    session: Session = Depends(get_session),
    query: Optional[Props] = Query(
            default=select(PropsTable), description="It is optional"
        )):
```

but getting this error ->

```
raise fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError(
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that typing.Optional
```

Created a model like this

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Props(BaseModel):
    query: Optional[str]
```

Comment: No this does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this worked fine, I wanted to pass RAW SQL query from FastAPI swagger UI.
This is what I done in the routes

```
def get_props_query(
    *,
    session: Session = Depends(get_session),
    query: Union[str, None] = Query(default=None, description="It is optional"),
):
```